# Using OpenNMS to monitor SNMP, can't see MIB data

Tags: snmp, opennms

I have a MIB with oids and events.  The device the MIB relates to is online.  OpenNMS sees and gathers information about the interfaces on the appliance, as well as the linux variant it is running.

but it doesn't see the other oids (or I can't find/chart them).

The gui reports Polling Status (Managed) and Package (uti_p).  The uti_p package is

```
<package name="uti_p">
  <filter>IPADDR != '0.0.0.0'</filter>
  <include-range begin="10.19.0.200" end="10.19.0.210" />
  <rrd step="300">
    <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:2016</rra>
    <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:12:1488</rra>
    <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:288:366</rra>
    <rra>RRA:MAX:0.5:288:366</rra>
    <rra>RRA:MIN:0.5:288:366</rra>
  </rrd>
  <service name="ICMP" interval="300000" user-defined="false" status="on">
    <parameter key="retry" value="2" />
    <parameter key="timeout" value="3000" />
    <parameter key="rrd-repository" value="/var/lib/opennms/rrd/response" />
    <parameter key="rrd-base-name" value="icmp" />
    <parameter key="ds-name" value="icmp" />
  </service>
  <service name="SNMP" interval="300000" user-defined="false" status="on">
    <parameter key="retry" value="2"/>
    <parameter key="timeout" value="3000"/>
    <parameter key="port" value="161"/>
    <parameter key="oid" value=".1.3.6.1.4.1.nnnn"/>
  </service>
  <downtime interval="30000" begin="0" end="300000" />
  <downtime interval="300000" begin="300000" end="43200000" />
  <downtime interval="600000" begin="43200000" end="432000000" />
  <downtime begin="432000000" delete="true" />
</package>
```

I have a collectd-configuration

```
<package name="uti_p">
    <filter>IPADDR != '0.0.0.0'</filter>
    <include-range begin="10.19.0.200" end="10.19.0.210"/>
    <service name="SNMP" interval="30000" user-defined="false" status="on">
        <parameter key="collection" value="HsmLan"/>
        <parameter key="port" value="161"/>
        <parameter key="retry" value="3"/>
        <parameter key="timeout" value="3000"/>
        <parameter key="thresholding-enabled" value="true"/>
    </service>
</package>
```

The .../rrd/snmp/{node} directory does not show any collection of data for the various oids that I am looking for.

In response to comments:

```
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c FIPS14023 10.19.0.204 iso.3.6.1.4.1.nnnn
...
iso.3.6.1.4.1.nnnn.1.1.10.0 = INTEGER: 29
iso.3.6.1.4.1.nnnn.1.1.11.0 = STRING: "29.0"
...
```

i.e., it returns the expected data from the MIB.

The Community set in OpenNMS is FIPS14023, and the automatic discovery process finds the node.

```
Node    Hsm.204
Interface   10.19.0.204
Polling Status  Managed
Polling Package     uti_p
Monitor Class   org.opennms.netmgt.poller.monitors.SnmpMonitor
Service Parameters
oid     .1.3.6.1.4.1.nnnn
```

The Requisition name for the class of appliance is correct.

I just can find where the above String "29.0" is supposed to appear.  As I understand it, the data should be collected into RRD db files, but the node Database IDs never show up in the /etc/opennms/rrdsnmp directory.

```
riw@riw-ubuntu-vbox:/etc/opennms/rrdsnmp$ ls
riw@riw-ubuntu-vbox:/etc/opennms/rrdsnmp$
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would debug the SNMP access as the following with assuming you have SNMP v2 setup:

1. Test access to SNMP agent from your OpenNMS server with snmpwalk -v 2c -c
2. OpenNMS associates SNMP community strings with the IP address. You can verify this in the Web UI in "Admin -> Configure OpenNMS -> Configure OpenNMS Community Names by IP Address" and use the "Lookup" field. It will show you which SNMP community is configured for your device and fix this if necessary.
3. Go to the node page and rescan the server and see if the "SNMP Attributes" fields with IP and physical interfaces get filled.

If Step 1 does not give you the full SNMP tree you have to fix your surrounding configuration, IP tables or SNMP agent configuration for views and community.

Comment: 1) snmpwalk did show the data I'm looking for. 2) I've fiddled with the community names in the admin section you name, but I'll fire up the VM and see what they are currently set to just in case I changed them, 3) I'll rescan.  I'll edit the original question with the results.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are defining a different collection set "HsmLan" over the default collection for SNMP in collectd?

Be sure to include the collection service at the bottom of collectd-configuration.xml for HsmLan, ala:

```
   <collector service="HsmLan" class-name="org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.SnmpCollector"/>
```

If there is, you need to define this "snmp-collection" in datacollection-config.xml and include collections via the  tag which references collections named in xml files (that have OIDs, etc) in etc/datacollection/

The poller-configuration.xml you listed at the top has no bearing on data collection.  It is for service polling.

Comment: Mainly it is because I am all-out confused about how this thing is set up.  Data wasn't being collected via the default collection, so I tried ginning up my own -- which also didn't work.  But asking a question that says, in effect "the default doesn't work" would have gotten ignored (Stack Overflow == show your work or don't expect an answer...)